# Flutter/dart: setState() called after dispose() error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running into a 'setState() called after dispose()' error.
I understand that this is caused because I am trying to update a component that is not present anymore.

So the issue is occuring when I click the button 'Login', which calls the funtion "_submitFormOnLogin"

Below is the code snip where I think the problem might be

```
  void _submitFormOnLogin() async {
    final isValid = _loginFormKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _emailTextController.text.trim().toLowerCase(),
            password: _passTextController.text.trim());
        Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null;
      } catch (error) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        GlobalMethod.showErrorDialog(error: error.toString(), ctx: context);
        print('error occurred! $error');
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Below is all the code for that page::

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ijob_clone_app/ForgetPassword/forget_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:ijob_clone_app/SingUpPage/signup_screen.dart';

import '../Services/global_methods.dart';
import '../Services/global_variables.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late Animation<double> _animation;
  late AnimationController _animationController;

  final TextEditingController _emailTextController =
      TextEditingController(text: '');
  final TextEditingController _passTextController =
      TextEditingController(text: '');

  final FocusNode _passFocusNode = FocusNode();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  bool _obscureText = true;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _emailTextController.dispose();
    _passTextController.dispose();
    _passFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 20));
    _animation =
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.linear)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {});
          })
          ..addStatusListener((animationStatus) {
            if (animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed) {
              _animationController.reset();
              _animationController.forward();
            }
          });
    _animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
  }



  void _submitFormOnLogin() async {
    final isValid = _loginFormKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _emailTextController.text.trim().toLowerCase(),
            password: _passTextController.text.trim());
        Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null;
      } catch (error) {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
        GlobalMethod.showErrorDialog(error: error.toString(), ctx: context);
        print('error occurred! $error');
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: loginUrlImage,
        placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
          'assets/images/wallpaper.jpg',
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        alignment: FractionalOffset(_animation.value, 0),
      ),
      Container(
          color: Colors.black54,
          child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 80),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 80, right: 80),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/login.png')),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Form(
                      key: _loginFormKey,
                      child: Column(children: [
                        TextFormField(
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context)
                                .requestFocus(_passFocusNode),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                            controller: _emailTextController,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                                return 'Please enter a valid Email address';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                hintText: 'Email',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                                ))),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            focusNode: _passFocusNode,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                            controller: _passTextController,
                            obscureText: !_obscureText,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value!.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                                return 'please enter a valid password';
                              } else {
                                return null;
                              }
                            },
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    child: Icon(
                                      _obscureText
                                          ? Icons.visibility
                                          : Icons.visibility_off,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )),
                                hintText: 'Password',
                                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                                focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                                errorBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ])),
                  const SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => ForgetPassword()));
                          },
                          child: const Text('Forget password?',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                              )))),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: _submitFormOnLogin,
                      color: Colors.cyan,
                      elevation: 8,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13)),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Text('Login',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height:40),
                  Center(
                    child:RichText(
                      text:TextSpan(
                        children:[
                          const TextSpan(
                            text:'Do not have an account?',
                            style:TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const TextSpan(text: '   '),
                          TextSpan(
                            recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                              ..onTap = () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp() )),
                            text: 'SignUp',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            )
                          )
                        ]
                      )
                    )
                  )

                ],
              )))
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: One potential problem is that you unconditionally call `setState` after `await`ing an asynchronous operation.  What if your widget is no longer valid by the time the asynchronous operation completes?

Comment: Please note that `    super.initState();` should be the *first* thing called in the override subroutine.

Comment: Before calling the setState({}) check if it is mounted or not. Like this if(mounted){ setState({}) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A widget can be deleted during an asynchronous operation. This case is called an async gap. Read more about it [here](https://andrewzuo.com/notes-on-the-lint-do-not-use-buildcontexts-across-async-gaps-b0931bf8dad5).

You need to check the mounted state before setState:

```
if (mounted) {
  setState(() {
    // do smith
  }
}
```

or

```
if (mounted) {
  Navigator.canPop(context) ? Navigator.pop(context) : null;
}
```